# Does gracenote mobile support bitcode?

Tags: ios, ios9, gracenote, bitcode

I just downloaded the latest version of the iOS Gracenote SDK and had got a linker error saying it needed bitcode. I can compile if I turn off the botched option, so it's okay for now, but I'd like to know if GraceNote is planning to update their SDK or if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: You should ask this of the developer of the SDK. No point asking here.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. However, the developer closed their SDK forum and said to ask all questions here :-/